# How to avoid bottleneck performance?

Tags: performance, distributed-system

A distributed system is described as scalable if it remains effective when there is a significant increase the number of resources and the number of users.  However, these systems sometimes face performance bottlenecks. How can these be avoided?

Comment: Yes. But can't get an accurate answer.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. IMO many systems nowadays make use of [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) to pre-render commonly accessed data, e.g. ViewModels for UI, often storing this in a NoSQL ReadStore.

Comment: The question is vague? But that's the question my lecturer give me. I can't tel him this question is vague. Haha, anyway thanks for the replies.

Comment: Your lecturer did **not** ask this question here, you did. So you are responsible for the question, to ensure it meets the style of a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular it lacks the results of your own _good faith_ effort to [answer the question yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). As your question is currently, people can only offer suggestions and opinions, but there is no means of separating better answers from poor ones.

Answer (score 2):

The question is pretty broad, and depends entirely on what the system is doing.

Here are some things I've seen in systems to reduce bottlenecks.

- Use **caches**, reducing network and disk bottlenecks. But remember that knowing when to evict from a cache eviction can a hard problem in some situations.
- Use **message queues** to decouple components in the system. This way you can add more hardware to specific parts of the system that need it.
- **Delay computation** when possible (often by using message queues). This takes the heat off the system during high-processing times.
- Of course, design the system for **parallel processing** wherever possible. One host doing processing is NOT scalable. Note: most relational databases fall into the one-host bucket, this is why **NoSQL** has become suddenly popular; but not always appropriate (theoretically).
- Use **eventual consistency** if possible. Strong consistency is much harder to scale.

Some are proponents for CQRS and DDD. Though I have never seen or designed a "CQRS system" nor a "DDD system," those have definitely affected the way I design systems.

There is a lot of overlap in the points above; some the techniques may use some of the others.

But, experience (your own and others) eventually teaches you about scalable systems. I keep up-to-date by reading about designs from google, amazon, twitter, facebook, and the like. Another good starting point is the [high-scalability blog](http://highscalability.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on a point discussed in the abover post, I would like to add that what you need for your distributed system is a distributed cache, so that when you intend on scaling your application the distributed cache acts like a "elastic" data-fabric meaning that you can increase storage capacity of the cache without compromising on performance and at the same time giving you a relaible platform that is accessible to multiple applications.

One such [distributed caching solution is NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/distributed-cache-features.html). Do take a look!